# Display data of primeng carousel into 2 rows

Tags: angular, carousel, primeng

I am using primeng carousel to display the data/items but the requirements ask for the items to be displayed into 2 different rows per page 5 items for each row and then when we click next we are presented with the other items the 11nth. I have tried to manipulate it as much as I can but with no success at best I display 5 items visually correct but when I set `[numVisible]="10"` it all clumps up into a single row.
Does anyone know how you can achieve this with primeng carousel?

[image]

[image]

```html
<p-carousel [value]="laboratori" [numVisible]="10" [numScroll]="5" [responsive]="true"
    *ngIf="step == 0 && laboratori.length != 0">
    <ng-template let-lab pTemplate="item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="lab-item" style="height: 90%;">
          <div class="card card-shadow" [ngClass]="lab?.nome != laboratorioSelected?.nome? 'tail': 'tailSelected'"
            type="button" (click)="selectLaboratorio(lab)">
            <div class="card-body" style=" align-self: center;">
              <h5 class="card-title mb-0">{{lab?.nome}}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-carousel>
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by 5x5 ?
Carousel from PrimeNg does take a list of items, if you want it multi-dimensional, you would need to prepare the list before, and it would take a loop with *ngFor inside the ng-template. What do you think ?

Comment: Hello I mean 2 rows with 5 items each. You mean I have to use another loop inside the ng-template ? because I thought primeng carousel or other components like tables already loop through arrays.

Comment: Well there little relation between Prime tables and carousel. My question is : what do you mean by a "row" in your carousel ? There is no row in Prime carousel, just a list that you handle with parameters. I suggest you get this stackblitz and fork it, and reproduce a simple use case to show your need : https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-carousel-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yL8q6p3c/ something like this in this case it uses owl carousel and maybe it cannot be done with primeng carousel but after all the searching and testing I thought maybe just ask if it's doable or not.

Comment: This example is not a carousel, right ? So, I don't know how you would want such a carousel to behave, but Prime carousel is not intended to display multiple rows. But if you wanted to display those 10 items, and then 10 more items the same way, you would need to create an Array with a complex item object inside, and like I said, for each item, you loop on the 10 children each time. Not that complex I guess :) Each Item has simply 10 children.

Comment: Thank you very much your idea worked and tbh I didn't quite understand it but a college of mine helped me understand and implement it and really liked your logic here. Why don't you write it as an answer so I can check it as correct. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, I just added an answer, I'm glad it helped even a litte bit ! PrimeNg are great components !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to display those 10 items, and then 10 more items the same way, you would need to create an Array with a complex item object inside, and like I said, for each item, you loop on the 10 children each time. Not that complex I guess :) Each Item has simply 10 children.

Actually, if you look closely at your example on fiddle, it does exactly what I told you about, meaning they group the items to have kind of "rows" :

```html
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4> <h4>2</h4></div>
</div>
```

The items are "grouped" by 2.
So if you wanted to do that, just group your items like I said in your data, it would look like something :

```js
data = [
  { obj1: some, obj2: thing },
  { ... }
]
```

Or you group by 10 ... your choice really :)